# How do you add new projects to a Visual Studio Solutions file?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I want to know how we can add projects in single solution file.

When I create the solution and try to add projects in it, the solution file is not visible.

How can I add projects/websites to the solution file?

Comment: When you add Projects, you choose File -> Add -> Existing Project, select a .csproj or .vbproj file and it opens without error but doesn't show up in Project Explorer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Tools" menu -> "Options" dialog -> "Projects and Solutions" tree node -> "General" tree node -> "Always show solution" checkbox. Make sure it's ticked.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574459/1585164
Option has been removed but set to true.

Answer (score 4):

`File => New ...`  works for me.

Comment: I have tried the same way my solution file is added but when i ma adding the projects in it the solution file is not in Solution explorer,now it shows the project i have add in the solutionfile

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio for Mac, right-click the solution name in the Solution Pad, then choose **Add** ➞ **Add New Project**.

Answer (score 1):

File -> add -> new website

Answer (score 1):

Go to File --> Add --> Existing project

[VS 2022]

Answer (score 0):

Reset your VS settings.

Tools => Import and Export Settings...

Choose 'General Development Settings' from settings collection.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem today, and the solution was a little different.  I was actively debugging a program and wanted to add a new project to a solution.  I was not able to right click->Add until I exited the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps, From Start to End, using Web API and MVC as examples:

Create new project->Web API->rename  MainSolutionName.Web.API

Solution->rename->MainSolutionName

uncheck 'place solution and project in the same directory'

*Once Created*

Right-Click -> MainSolutionName

Add->New Project->MVC

project name->rename->MainSolutionName.Web

These are the steps I used.