# Visual Studio 2019 "Always show solution" Option Removed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

There used to be an option in Visual Studio 2017 and prior to turn off "Always show solution." This setting is missing in Visual Studio 2019 and appears to have been removed.

Unfortunately this causes trouble when using the 'Open Web Site' feature as I often do, because 'Save All' prompts to create a .sln file which I do not want.

Visual Studio 2019:

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio 2019 options]

Visual Studio 2017:

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio 2017 options]

Has this option been removed completely or just relocated and the name changed?

Searching for 'Always show solution' in the Visual Studio 2019 options window returns no results.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunate but yes, this is true as mentioned in the [Release notes for VS 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.0):

> *The solution options Show advanced build configurations, **Always show solution**, and Save new projects when created have been removed due to low usage. These values have been set to their default value of True.*

If you think having this is important for you and may also benefit others in the community, please provide submit a suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).